# Modify dataframe values in one column based on values in another column

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, replace, append

I'm pretty sure there's a very easy solution to this, but I've been struggling for literally hours trying to find it!

Use the following dataframe for the issue:

```
data = {"Market": ['NYSE','TSX','SPTSX','TSX60','SP500'],"Ticker": ['AGM.A','AEM','CCL.B','BBD-B','BRK.B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

All I want to do is:

1. Replace any '.' in Symbol with "-"
2. If the string 'TSX' appears anywhere within the Market column, then append '.TO' onto the Symbol.

The final tickers should be AGM-A, AEM.TO, CCL-B.TO, BBD-B.TO, BRK-B

I've tried variations of the following to no success:

```
if df['Market'].str.find('TSX').any(): 
    df['Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].str.replace('.','-') + '.TO'

for x in df['Market']:
    if x.str.find('TSX').any():
        data['Ticker'] = data['Ticker']+".TO"

df.loc[df.Market.str.contains('TSX').any(), 'Ticker'] = df.Ticker + ".TO"
#df['Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].astype(str) + '.TO'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to apply multiple string operations, it's often more efficient to avoid pandas functions and to fallback to pure python. Here you can achieve your goal in a single pass with a list comprehension:

```
df['Ticker'] = [t.replace('.', '-') + ('.TO' if 'TSX' in m else '')
                for t, m in zip(df['Ticker'], df['Market'])]
```

This is 2 to 10 times faster than pandas functions.

Output:

```
  Market    Ticker
0   NYSE     AGM-A
1    TSX    AEM.TO
2  SPTSX  CCL-B.TO
3  TSX60  BBD-B.TO
4  SP500     BRK-B
```

Comment: I get a "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'" even though I checked the df.dtype and they are object, not float.  I have Python 3.8 in case that matters. I recently updated pandas. I don't use python very often, so maybe some other aspects need updating? Could that be the source of the error?

Comment: This means you have NaNs, you can thus use: `[t if pd.isna(t) else (t.replace('.', '-') + ('.TO' if 'TSX' in m else '') for t, m in zip(df['Ticker'], df['Market'])]`

Comment: Oh, I just realized a new mistake. My CSV file which I import as the dataframe, has a ticker = 'NA' (National Bank of Canada), and on doing the import, the NA was converted to NaN, which then causes the error. I didn't catch that before, and it was probably why nothing I was trying before worked - because I knew I had no NaN's in my CSV, and therefore assumed I had no NaN's in my dataframe either. The error should have been a trigger for me to take another look! Rookie mistake. I fixed the read_csv to include "keep_default_na=False" and now your original code snip works perfectly.

Comment: Good catch, this NaN detection is both useful and annoying, depending on your data. I've been there too. I wish "NA" wasn't in the default list ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are close, need remove `any` and replace all values first:

```
df.Ticker = df.Ticker.str.replace('.','-', regex=True)
df.loc[df.Market.str.contains('TSX'), 'Ticker'] = df.Ticker + ".TO"
print (df)
  Market    Ticker
0   NYSE     AGM-A
1    TSX    AEM.TO
2  SPTSX  CCL-B.TO
3  TSX60  BBD-B.TO
4  SP500     BRK-B
```

If need replace only for values match condition:

```
m = df.Market.str.contains('TSX')
df.loc[m, 'Ticker'] = df.Ticker.str.replace('.','-', regex=True) + ".TO"
```

Or:

```
m = df.Market.str.contains('TSX')
df.loc[m, 'Ticker'] = df.loc[m, 'Ticker'].str.replace('.','-', regex=True) + ".TO"
```

Comment: When I try your first solution (just the string replace), it converts all the ticker text to --- (e.g., BRK-B becomes -----), which of course seems odd. I checked the df.dtypes and the columns are both 'object', if that matters. The second line then appends '.TO' properly, but because of the first line, I end up with '-----.TO'. This was partly the problem I had in the first place when I tried the replace - for some reason it was finding '.' even when there were none.

Comment: if I leave off the 'regex=True' part, it works fine.